# Can I re-print a past print without having the source document?

Tags: windows-10, printing

On Windows 10, I printed a document last night and, through pure carelessness, didn't save it (I was in a hurry and thought it'd be a one-off) and don't have the print to make a copy (it was a cut-out router template for some woodworking stuff, it's sawdust now), and now I want another copy of it.

I checked my printer (Brother MFC-9340CDW) but afaict it doesn't remember past documents for reprints. I also checked the software I made the document in (it does have auto-save capabilities) but, long story short, no luck there.

My question is: Does Windows cache these somewhere or maintain a history? Can I print another copy without having the source document available any more?

If it matters, it was the last thing I printed.

Comment: I know, I know, I don't need The Lecture™, heh... always save your work, kids!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working Print Queue (where Printouts go in Windows) empties out after printing. I see that here all the time.

So if there is nothing on the printer (very doubtful), then the printout is gone and you cannot retrieve it)

That is the way Windows printing works.

FWIW, I just printed some bills and checked the queue and it is indeed empty.

Comment: Darn it. Not the answer I needed; but the answer I deserved. I'll be back in 10 with a checkmark.

Comment: I think we have all made that mistake. So no "lecture" from me. Sorry that happened.